Writing a list of several mixed types of nested elements in a Google document (Python)
Prerequisites:
Assume that I've created a Google service account, and I've a Google document ID doc_ID.
Problem:
When I've only 2 types of elements (nested list and normal text), subsequent to the suggestion of @Tanaike https://stackoverflow.com/a/78541593/25276165, I successfully wrote the contents to a Google document. Now I want to generalize my list to include various other kind of elements. Thereby, my lists looks like the following:
my_list =
[
    "# Top-level Heading",
    "This is the first normal text line, without any itemized list format.",
    "* This is the first outermost list item (number)",
    "  * This is the first level-one indented list item (alpha)",
    "This is the final normal text line, without any itemized list format.",
    "# Top-level Heading",
    "* This is the second outermost list item (number) under the heading, with new numbering",
    "  * This is the second level-one indented list item (alpha) under the heading",
    "This is the final normal text line, without any itemized list format.",
]

My Attempts:
To cater various types of list elements, my first line of thought is to use a for loop with if conditions, as shown below:
requests = []
for item in my_list:
    if item.startswith("# "):
        text = item[2:] + '\n'
        end_index = start_index + len(text)
        item_request = heading_request(text, start_index, end_index)
    elif item.startswith("* "):
        text = item[2:] + '\n'
        end_index = start_index + len(text)
        item_request = list_request(text, start_index, end_index)
    elif item.startswith("  * "):
        text = item[4:] + '\n'
        end_index = start_index + len(text)
        item_request = list_request(text, start_index, end_index)
    else:
        text = item + '\n'
        end_index = start_index + len(text)
        item_request = text_request(text, start_index, end_index)

    requests.append(item_request)
    start_index = end_index

Here, heading_request, list_request, or text_request are expected to contain all the desired fields and their values. For brevity reasons, I just list a brief hint of the code snippet for list_requests:
    {"insertText": {"text": list_text, 'location': {'index': start_list_index}}},
    {
        "createParagraphBullets": {
            'range': {'startIndex': start_list_index, 'endIndex': end_list_index},
            "bulletPreset": "NUMBERED_DECIMAL_ALPHA_ROMAN",
        }
    }

Expected Result

How can this be successfully programmed so that using Google Docs API, I can write to a Google document with desired nested indentation and text types?

In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your expected result?

@Tanaike: Thank you Sir. I've updated the question with expected result (and some minor formatting). Looking forward to your guidance/help.

Thank you for replying. In your script, indent_first = 18, indent_hang = 36 and indent_first = 36, indent_hang = 54 are used. But, it seems that in your showing image, the indents of each paragraph are the same for each nest. What are indent_first and indent_hang?

Also, what is it_request = list_request(text, start_index, end_index, indent_first, indent_hang)? And, in your showing image, it seems that the font size of Top-level Heading has changed. But, in your script, it is not reflected. So, I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike: Thank you very much for your prompt response Sir.
indent_first and indent_hang are the parameters for setting the magnitude values for the fields indentFirstLine (where the bullet or number is placed) and indentStart (the space between the bullet/number and the text). These can be set in paragraphStyle. In the image that I attached, the number 1 level has indent_start at 18, and indent_hang at 36. For the alpha-level nested list, these values are 36 and 54, respectively. Both the nested lists are placed according to these settings.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, in this question, the values indent_first and indent_hang are ignored. Is my understanding correct?

@Tanaike: Sir, to avoid repetitive multi-line insertion in each if block, I defined a function list_request, where I send the parameters text, start_index, end_index, indent_first, indent_hang. This function then returns expected request call, which has insertText, createParagraphBullets, and updateParagraphStyle dict-fields.
Please do not worry about your English. I can perfectly understand you. Your technical knowledge is very valuable and respectable for me.

Thank you for your reply. The values indent_first and indent_hang are ignored only for normal text, but for numbered list, they are useful. But if you have any better idea, I'll gladly consider removing them. My purpose of using them is for customizing the values for indentFirstLine and indentStart fields.

@Tanaike: And yes, the font for top-level heading is what Google docs has by default. Also, to avoid extended discussion, StackOverflow is suggesting to automatically move this discussion to chat. Since I'm new to StackOverFlow, please let me know if this should be moved to chat or not?

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between indent_first, indent_hang, and your expected result. Also I cannot understand the font for top-level heading is what Google docs has by default.. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution. I believe that when I can correctly understand your question, I can post an answer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'm not sure if you can follow the Chat message, so, I'm posting it here. Please pardon my ignorance.
Sir, Thank you again for promptly replying.

For your clarity, I've removed the parameters index_first and index_hang from my sample code. This I'll adapt it in my code later on.
In Google docs, the Heading 1 font is big. If it causes any difficulty in your understanding, please ignore it and use only normal text.


Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply Thank you Dr. @Tanaike.  From the image of your expected result, it seems that you are required to separate the lists by "Top-level Heading". No, I am assuming that my document may have a heading, then some text and lists, then some sub-headings or headings, and then some text and lists, etc. Breaking my input list into separate sub-lists will not support my full automation idea. Can we do it with one-single list?, I cannot understand what you want to do.

But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your actual expected result, I would like to think of a solution. In the current stage, I would like to delete my answer. Becuase from your reply, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I really apologize for my poor English skill again.

Dr. @Tanaike: Please do not worry about your English level. Let me try to explain again.
I've a list of markdown formatted text strings. In advance, I do not know where I will have headings, sub-headings, lists, or paragraphs. If we have such a general situation of mixed type of elements, then how can we adapt from your suggestions from today and yesterday so that we can process the whole list in one for-loop?

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your actual expected result, I would like to think of a solution. But, if you are required to get the answer immediately, please tell me.
